# How do I get the style to change based on the resolution of the device?

Tags: java, android, layout, styles

I've been working on my styles.xml file in order to make a button's text change color based on the resolution the app is loaded at. I did research on Styles and saw that there are qualifiers that can be added to designate the same style based on resolution, like "someStyle" and "someStyle_sw720" for the sw720 resolution. So I defined styles "BodyButtonStyle" and "BodyButtonStyle_sw720" in the app and gave them different values.

Both styles (default and the sw720 style) in styles.xml -

default:

```
<style name="BodyButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">280dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">50dp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/someText</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/rectangle_shape_button</item>
     <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

sw720:

```
<style name="BodyButtonStyle_sw720">
    <item name="android:layout_width">200dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">50dp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/someText</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPurple</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/rectangle_shape_button</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

In the layout I'm using, the style is set to "@style/BodyButtonStyle". I was under the assumption that if I loaded the app on any resolution other than the sw720 one, I'd get white (colorWhite) text, and the sw720 resolution would give it purple (colorPurple) text. I made this assumption because when there are multiple layouts in various resolutions, the app will pick the correct layout to use based on the resolution of the device (i.e a layout called "someLayout" has an sw720 version and an sw800 version, an sw800 device would load the sw800 layout).

Am I missing something here? I've also tried creating additional styles.xml files and loading them with their own "BodyButtonStyle" with different values based on resolution, but the app always seems to load the default regardless of the resolution. Ultimately, my goal is to get a single layout to load different values for elements based on the resolution of the device, and styles seemed to be the solution to that; however, although I seemingly followed the instructions for qualifiers (adding "_sw720" to the style name) it doesn't work, and only loads the default "BodyButtonStyle".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless things have changed since I last did this, you need to create separate styles.xml files for each resolution and place them in separate folders. The style name should be the same in both files. One will be placed in the "values" folder and the other one will be placed in "values-sw720dp".